# Alternative block cipher design paradigms to SP-networks and Feistel-like ones?

Tags: block-cipher, arx

Before I familiarized myself with the type of cryptography that became popular with the rise of the information age, I was very much into what the community seems to call "classical" ciphers: Caesar shift ciphers, the Vigenère cipher, [grilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grille_(cryptography)), [scytales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scytale), the Playfair cipher, the Enigma machine, and a few other techniques that might not qualify as ciphers. There were two kinds of ciphers, substitution and transposition (there was also a distinction between codes and ciphers). Still, I saw much more variety among cipher designs during that period of my life than after learning the classifications of information age algorithms used by modern cryptographers, like SP-networks and Feistel designs.

After understanding what a Feistel cipher—and all Feistel-like designs—is and what a substitution-permutation network is (before learning this one, I could actually see a little more variety), it seems like all I could up with were designs that fell into either category. Maybe three years ago, I discovered the ARX classification, and I figured that most ciphers that wound up in that those would always be Feistel-like ciphers. Later, I learned of [Speck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher)), which has a really unorthodox design (no swapping of the halves after each round). I didn't think of it as a different kind of structure until I saw that the [CryptoLUX article on lightweight block ciphers](https://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Block_Ciphers) lists it (ARX) as one. It also lists "generalized Feistel network" and "generalized Feistel structure", but I think those can be relabeled as "Feistel-like". And looking back on Speck, it seems like it cannot be classified as either a Feistel-like cipher or an SP-network.

So, my questions are:

- Are ARX block ciphers considered there own class of block cipher separate from SPNs and Feistel-like ones?
- Are there other schemes out there besides Feistel-like designs, SPNs, and ARX?

Comment: aren't you forgetting about Sponge based ?

Comment: Lai–Massey scheme. It divides the input in two halves but it is not feistel. It is used in IDEA. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lai%E2%80%93Massey_scheme

Answer (score 1):

### Are ARX block ciphers considered there own class of block cipher separate from SPNs and Feistel-like ones?

Generally speaking, yes. ARX ciphers typically only use simple CPU instructions (Addition, Rotation, and Xor) and are typically designed to ensure [constant time execution](https://www.bearssl.org/constanttime.html) as well as to facilitate efficient [SIMD implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).

The s-boxes and split state that are so prevalent among SPN and [Feistel Networks](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-unbalanced-feistel.pdf) generally aren't present in ARX designs. I'm sure if you wanted you could come up with/find an example of an ARX Feistel network or build an SP network from ARX instructions, but I'm not sure what advantages it would offer.

### Are there other schemes out there besides Feistel-like designs, SPNs, and ARX? Or is there really nothing new under the sun?

Typically, the ARX/SPN/Feistel part of the algorithm is used to create a "[pseudorandom permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation)", and the pseudorandom permutation is then used as part of a cipher construction to provide encryption.

The basic cipher construction is the iterated key or [Even-Mansour construction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/541.pdf). AES can be modeled like this, as an interleaved application of a key addition layer with the pseudorandom permutation.

A more recent cipher construction that can be built from an arbitrary pseudorandom permutation is the sponge construction. Technically the [duplex
construction](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-28496-0_19) is a stream cipher, rather then a block cipher. I think that this is actually a key point: [The presumption that a block cipher is the best way to encrypt is not necessarily true](https://www.nuee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/labs/tiwata/fse2017/Abstract_Joan_Daemen.pdf).

### Permutation based

Permutation based constructions are usually more versatile, and often times offer an all-in-one solution (authenticated encryption, hashing, MACs); While you could construct all of the above via a block cipher, it is much more straightforward from an implementation perspective to use a permutation based construction like the sponge construction.

### Homomorphic Ciphers

There exist "linear" secret key ciphers, like this one from [Fully Homomorphic Encryption Over The Integers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf). Typically these sorts of ciphers are designed to facilitate homomorphic encryption and/or to instantiate public key cryptosystems. They are often times built from number-theoretic perspectives, and clearly do not resemble any of the other cipher categories (and you would not use them for the same reasons).